# Is it possible to connect a VPS to another VPS

Tags: vps, filemaker

I would like to create an extremely low latency client - server environment to run FileMaker and FileMaker Server - essentially I would like to replicate a LAN, but on a

I currently have 1 VPS which runs my FileMaker Data Server (the "Server").
I would like to use another VPS (the "Client") to run my client software ie FileMaker Pro.
I would like to know if it possible to connect the Client directly to the Server (ie VPS 1 to VPS 2) essentially mimicking a LAN.
I would then be able to connect to the client using Microsoft Remote Desktop and run my complex data intensive queries at LAN (or faster) speeds, with extremely low latency.
Any thoughts welcome

Comment: Depends on how the vps environment is configured. There is no way to find lit but to try.

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities vary per platform and vendor. But some will allow you to create ***(anti-) affinity*** groups and/or rules.

Such affinity rules are intended to ensure that different  VPS instances do or don’t get launched on the same physical hypervisor.

When instances run on the same hypervisor you can get lower latency and higher bandwidth because their network traffic won’t have to leave the hypervisor anymore. The penalty for that potential performance increase is that an outage in that hypervisor will take out all instances. It sounds like you want to aim for that.

Anti-affinity is intended to spread out your instances over as many hypervisor so as possible to ensure that any outages will impact as few as possible instances.

Often affinity is a soft request and not a hard guarantee, so your mileage may vary.